# Istio when creating authorization policy for version 1.18.2 it is failing. Failed to create the authorizationpolicy

Tags: istio

Unable to create authorization policy for version `1.18.2` and encountering below error.

```
Failed to create the authorizationpolicy 'azure-token-validation'. 
Error: NotFound (404) : customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io 
"authorizationpolicys.security.istio.io" not found
```

Below is the `AuthorizationPolicy` definition

```yaml
    apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
    kind: AuthorizationPolicy
    metadata:
      name: azure-token-validation
      namespace: dev-istio-ns
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          istio: dev-ingress
      action: ALLOW
      rules:
      - from:
        - source:
            requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

I am able to create RequestAuthentication

```yaml
       apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
       kind: RequestAuthentication
       metadata:
         name: azure-token-validation
         namespace: dev-istio-ns
       spec:
         selector:
           matchLabels:
             istio: dev-ingress
         jwtRules:
           - issuer: "*" # https://sts.windows.net/<TenantID>/
             jwksUri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/discovery/v2.0/keys"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below error will be encountered when the following api / crd "authorizationpolicys.security.istio.io" is not properly registered or installed.

```
Failed to create the authorizationpolicy 'azure-token-validation'. Error: NotFound (404) : customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "authorizationpolicys.security.istio.io" not found
```

There is no problem with "AuthorizationPolicy" definition mentioned in the post.

This can be verified whether the api is installed by running

```
kubectl api-resources | grep authorizationpolicys
```

And also in general istio installation can be verified as mentioned in [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/istio-deploy-addon#verify-successful-installation)

Comment: Using the below command I am not able to see the authorization policy
kubectl api-resources | grep authorizationpolicys

I can see the CRD's are available using the below command

kubectl get crd -oname | grep --color=never 'istio.io'
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/authorizationpolicies.security.istio.io
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/requestauthentications.security.istio.o
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workloadgroups.networking.istio.io

How can we fix the issue? Installed Istio using helm https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/

Comment: Please re apply the CRD if that doesnt help i think only re installation of istio as an option.

Comment: I changed the API version string and it worked

apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error, your installation of the CRDs seems incorrect. There's no CRD name `authorizationpolicys.security.istio.io`.

However, there's a CRD called `authorizationpolicies.security.istio.io`. Check that your Istio CRD installation is correct and you haven't made a typo somewhere.